# Laser Collider As Long As Beam

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collider

```
{
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public Transform LaserHit;                        //this all works

    void Start()
    {
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer.useWorldSpace = true;                      //this works too
    }

    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.up);
        LaserHit.position = hit.point;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, transform.position);   //the laser is shown like i want
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, LaserHit.position);
    }
}
```

I have this laser script and it works! A laser IS shown, I want my player to die to the laser i have the death animation and respawning ALREADY MADE. For The Player To Die He has TO touch a BoxCollider2D preferebly one set to trigger. I want to put the BoxCollider2D (preferebly set to trigger) for as long as the laser beam is, so that you dont die where thre isnt a laser beam shown.
I hope i made myself clear and Please anwser :D thanks

Comment: like creating a collider with code that is set to be as long as the beam of hte laser no matter the size of the beam

Comment: there is no limit to your raycast if it doesn't hit anything ... is it supposed to be like that?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
public Collider collider;
```

and then

```
var delta = LaserHit.position - transform.position;
collider.transform.position = (LaserHit.position + transform.position) * 0.5f;
collider.transform.right = delta; 
collider.transform.localScalee = new Vector3(delta.magnitude, 0.1f, 1f);
```